# Repopulate a DataTables table with the result of a XHR

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, xmlhttprequest, exist-db

I'm using Jquery DataTables for displaying a long list of records:

```
<table id="mainTable" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Sender</th>
                        <th>Recipient</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id='mainTableRows'>
                    <tr><td><td></tr>[etc...]
                </tbody>
```

The table gets populated (via a XQuery, not DataTables) and intiated upon page loading:

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('#mainTable').DataTable({ }) } );
```

So far, so good. I then want the user to be able to generate new data by using a search form. The search form is something like:

```
<form id="advancedSearch" action="modules/advanced_search.xq" method="post" onsubmit="advancedSearch(this);">
```

The .xq file returns a JSON like this:

```
[ {
  "dateSent" : "1768-01-19",
  "personSentFullName" : "Robert Thomas",
  "personReceivedFullName" : "Richard Morris",
  "id" : "e34712"
}, {
  "dateSent" : "1768-04-23",
  "personSentFullName" : "Robert Thomas",
  "personReceivedFullName" : "Richard Morris",
  "id" : "e34716"
}, {
  "dateSent" : "1768-10-25",
  "personSentFullName" : "Robert Thomas",
  "personReceivedFullName" : "Richard Morris",
  "id" : "e34779"
}, {
  "dateSent" : "1769-01-16",
  "personSentFullName" : "Robert Thomas",
  "personReceivedFullName" : "Richard Morris",
  "id" : "e34805"
} ]
```

How can I use this data to repopulate my table? This is my JavaScript function called by the form submit:

```
function advancedSearch (oFormElement) {
event.preventDefault()

       $('#mainTable').DataTable()

               .clear()
               .draw();                       
    const oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const data = new FormData(oFormElement)

    oReq.open("post", oFormElement.action, true);
    oReq.send(data);

    oReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            const result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            if (result == null)
            {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "empty"
            } else {

                $('#mainTable').DataTable( {
                       ajax: result
                   } );
            }

        }   
}

}
```

I get a `Cannot reinitialise DataTable` error. I've even tried repopulating the table 'by hand', with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

document.getElementById("mainTableRows").innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + result[i].id + '</td><td>' + result[i].dateSent + '</td><td>' + result[i].personSentFullName + '</td><td>' + result[i].personReceivedFullName + '</td><tr>'
```

I just get a discrepancy, since the table keeps reloading the old 'full' data, or I get the data in the table without pagination, or other issues which tell me that the table is not reinitialised properly. `$destroy` just reloads the old data, and setting `serverSide: false` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by returning a JSON in this format (i.e. with a numeric sequence in the attribute names):

```
[ {
  "0" : "e34712",
  "1" : "1768-01-19",
  "2" : "Robert Thomas",
  "3" : "Richard Morris"
}, {
  "0" : "e34716",
  "1" : "1768-04-23",
  "2" : "Robert Thomas",
  "3" : "Richard Morris"
}, {
  "0" : "e34779",
  "1" : "1768-10-25",
  "2" : "Robert Thomas",
  "3" : "Richard Morris"
}, {
  "0" : "e34805",
  "1" : "1769-01-16",
  "2" : "Robert Thomas",
  "3" : "Richard Morris"
} ]
```

and this is my working JavaScript:

```
"use strict";

function advancedSearch (oFormElement) {
    event.preventDefault()
                    var table = $('#mainTable').DataTable()
                    table.clear()


    if (oFormElement.pe1id.value == '' && oFormElement.pe2id.value == '') {
        alert('You have to enter at least one person.');
        return false;
    } else {

        const oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const data = new FormData(oFormElement)

        oReq.open("post", oFormElement.action, true);
        oReq.send(data);

        oReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
                const result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                if (result == null)


                {
                        table.draw()
                } else {
                     {

                        table.rows.add(result)
                         table.draw();


                }

            } 
        }        


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reinitialise you table, and destroying it and re-creating it is just a waste of processing power. Instead of using JavaScript to perform your Ajax request, use the built-in Ajax processor, it's a lot easier. Since you appear to be already using the built-in Ajax to load your table initially you can just set the URL to a different one.

```js
const mainTable = $('#mainTable').DataTable({
    options
});

mainTable.ajax.url('modules/advanced_search.xq').load();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I wrote I do not initially load my table via Ajax, but server-side via eXist-db modules. I actually just managed to have it working just by returning my response JSON as [ { "0" : "...", "1" : "...", "2" : "...", "3" :"..."} ] . Go figure.